# Tic Tac Toe javascript. How to store player wins and to alert if there is a tie?

Tags: javascript

I am currently creating a javascript tic tac toe game. I manage to get to display which player won. Somehow I currently struggle how to display a message when the game ends with a draw.

One more thing is how do I create a scoreboard and alert it when one of the player has won the game three times.

here is my code.

```
<html>
<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="startGame();">
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <h2>By Irsyad</h2>
  <div id ="message"><h3> messages will go here<h3></div>
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:startGame();">Restart</a>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="s1" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
      <td id="s2" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
      <td id="s3" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="s4" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
      <td id="s5" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
      <td id="s6" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="s7" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
      <td id="s8" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
      <td id="s9" class="square" onclick="nextMove(this);"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the javascript.

```
function startGame () {

for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
     clearBox(i);
}
  document.turn = "X" ;
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    document.turn = "O" ;
  }
  document.winner = null;
  setMessage(document.turn + " gets to start");
}

function setMessage(msg) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerText = msg;
}

function nextMove(square) {
  if (document.winner != null) {
    setMessage(document.winner + " already won the game");
  }
  else if (square.innerText == ""){
    square.innerText = document.turn;
    switchTurn();
  } else {
    setMessage("That square is already used");
  }
}

function switchTurn() {
   if (checkForWinner(document.turn)) {
     setMessage("Congratulations, " + document.turn + " ! You win!");
     document.winner = document.turn;
   }
   else if (document.turn == "X") {
       document.turn = "O";
       setMessage("It's " + document.turn + " 's turn")

   } else {
      document.turn = "X";
      setMessage("It's " + document.turn + " 's turn")

   }
}

function checkForWinner(move) {
  var result= false;
  if (checkRow(1, 2, 3, move) ||
      checkRow(4, 5, 6, move) ||
      checkRow(7, 8, 9, move) ||
      checkRow(1, 4, 7, move) ||
      checkRow(2, 5, 8, move) ||
      checkRow(3, 6, 9, move) ||
      checkRow(1, 5, 9, move) ||
      checkRow(3, 5, 7, move)) {

      result = true;
      return result;
      }

}

function checkRow(a, b, c, move) {
   var result = false;
   if (getBox(a) == move && getBox(b) == move && getBox(c) == move){
     result = true;
   }
   return result;
}

function getBox(number) {
   return document.getElementById("s" + number).innerText;
}

function clearBox(number) {
  document.getElementById("s" + number).innerText = "";
}
```

Comment: For the scoreboard, simply do `var scoreboard = {X: 0, O:0};
function updateScoreBoard (winner) {
 if (++scoreboard[winner]==3) {
  alert("Game over! " + winner + " has won three matches");
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Updated: To check for a tie:

```
var moveCounter = 0;

function switchTurn() {
    if (checkForWinner(document.turn)) {
        setMessage("Congratulations, " + document.turn + " ! You win!");
        document.winner = document.turn;
        moveCounter = 0;
        updateScoreBoard(document.winner);
    } else if (moveCounter==9){
        setMessage("It's a tie!");
    }
    else if (document.turn == "X") {
        moveCounter++;
        document.turn = "O";
        setMessage("It's " + document.turn + " 's turn")

    } else {
        moveCounter++;
        document.turn = "X";
        setMessage("It's " + document.turn + " 's turn")

    }
}


function checkForWinner(move) {
    var result = false;
    if (checkRow(1, 2, 3, move) ||
        checkRow(4, 5, 6, move) ||
        checkRow(7, 8, 9, move) ||
        checkRow(1, 4, 7, move) ||
        checkRow(2, 5, 8, move) ||
        checkRow(3, 6, 9, move) ||
        checkRow(1, 5, 9, move) ||
        checkRow(3, 5, 7, move)) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For the scoreboard, simply do

```
var scoreboard = {X: 0, O:0};
function updateScoreBoard (winner) {
    if (++scoreboard[winner]==3) {
        setMessage("Game over! " + winner + " has won three matches");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. The scoreboard works perfectly. Unfortunately the tie message does not work. I'll try to tweak around. Thanks

Comment: @Irsyad14 Yes, I think I found the mistake. Updated the answer, you can check if it works